# Changing the binded value of a label?

Tags: java, javafx

This code binds a Label to an updating SimpleIntegerPropertyValue which is counting down from 10 - 1.

```
view.OVERALL_PROGRESS_LABEL.textProperty().bind(timeSeconds.divide(100).asString());
```

How can I bind specific values depending on what currently this `timeSeconds` value is? For instance if the value of `timeSeconds > 500` then display **"Greater"** otherwise display **"Less"**.

I have tried binding a method which returns an `ObservableValue` but it is not function correctly. *(just manipulating the numbers to see if there is a change)*

```
private void someMethod(){
     view.OVERALL_PROGRESS_LABEL.textProperty().bind(test2());
}

private ObservableValue<? extends String> test2() {

    ObservableValue<String> test;
    if (timeSeconds.getValue() < 500){
        test = timeSeconds.multiply(1000).asString();
    } else {
        test = timeSeconds.divide(1000).asString();
    }
    return test;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Bindings`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) to create bindings based on condition.

```
view.OVERALL_PROGRESS_LABEL.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(timeSeconds.
                              greaterThan(500)).then("Greater").otherwise("Less"));
```